# Jasper subreport arent receiving any F{}

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

In my master report, I have a subreport tag:

```
<subreport>
    <subreportParameter name="quotaSanitarySeal">
        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{quotaSanitarySeal}]]>
        </subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></dataSourceExpression>
    <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "subReportTest.jasper"]]>
    </subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

But when I generate it, It doesn't show up the value of the field...

```
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{quotaSanitarySeal} == 0.0 ? "" : $F{quotaSanitarySeal}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

What I'm missing? I must do something in my subReportTest?

Comment: 1. Why you use parameter with expression $F{quotaSanitarySeal} and dataSourceExpression $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}, which contain $F{quotaSanitarySeal}? 2. $F{quotaSanitarySeal} == 0.0 (field is number?), Text field expression "= 0.0 ? "" (string?) : $F{quotaSanitarySeal} (number?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a field or Variable or Parameter to sub-report. Those values will be stored inside Parameter section of subreport.

So when you are passing a field, you have to create a respective Parameter field inside the sub-report, in your case create a parameter called `"quotaSanitarySeal"` in your sub report. Once you added the parameter, then you can pass a value to the parameter from a master report like below,

```
<subreport>
    <subreportParameter name="quotaSanitarySeal">
        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{quotaSanitarySeal}]]>
        </subreportParameterExpression>
    </subreportParameter>
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]</dataSourceExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "subReportTest.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

Once you have successfully passed the value then you can use the parameter like below inside the subreport,

```
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{quotaSanitarySeal} == 0.0 ? "" : $P{quotaSanitarySeal}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Note: For `"subreportExpression"`, you need not set the type `class="java.lang.String"`.

Hope this helps.